# Error while running Package in Command prompt , No module found

Tags: python, modulenotfounderror

I have created a package named as patterns along with test.py,
test.py has the following code lines:

```
from patterns.shapes import *
square()
```

[Module Error]

I have copied the test.py file to the same location F:, where I trying to run via command prompt.

To gain access to this package from any location I have installed it using `pip install .`  in the windows command prompt, which was successful, but when I try to access the file test.py I am getting the error as below :

```
F:\>py test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 1, in <module>
    from patterns.shapes import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'patterns'
```

My package folder is stored in a different drive.

Comment: Does pip list show the package ?

Answer (score 0):

While working on a python project,  one must always work in a `virtual environment`. Please check if you have your virtual environment activated. If not, then follow the steps:

1. `cd your_working_directory`
2. `virtualenv environment_name` where `environment_name` can be any name you want.
3. `environment_name/Scripts/activate` if on `Windows`

Or `environment_name/bin/activate` if on `MacOS`

Then after activating the environment you can install all the dependencies using pip. i.e `pip install patterns`